# Flink - From streaming to batch - Start job from another

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to know, if there is a simple way to launch a Flink job from another Job..

I have a streaming job, listening on the file system for new file, and I need to process thoses files (packaged) in a batch way (join between files...)

So I have my batch job doing the processing, but I want to launch it from my streaming job, so I can process files as they arrived

Is there a way to do it beautifuly ?
I though using the RestClusterClient.

Generally, i want to go from streaming to batch
Windowing in streaming doesn't allow me to do advanced things like in batch Dataset API

Another question is, how can we execute operation on the master (JobManager) to use  executionEnvironment in dataflow instead of executing it on a worker (with "standard" operations)

Thanks for your help
Regards,
Bastien

Comment: What do you want to do in batching that you can't do in streaming?

Comment: Hi gcandal, a lot a things, I want to process it in a bounded way : reading files & storing it in datasets for join & sink into a database.. batch is pretty relevant for this kind of task.  
I can of course read it into a Datastream, but i'll need to insert somehow a EOF stream, and using the window assigner / trigger on element..
Once I got the window i.e my "bounded" datastream, I will be lock to do (one) window functions with my WindowedDatastream and I will not be able to use high level operation like I would do in Dataset and chaining operations on my data

Comment: This would be very nice to switch from WindowedDataStream to DataSet-like context,   

The way to go is to use the REST API to upload & run, as the ClusterClient need the classpath of all the jar file (flink lib & program jar) and it is intended to be used by Flink internally